# Exporting entitlements.plist from the app using the codesign utility gives warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, codesign

Export entitlements.plist from the app using the codesign utility

codesign -d --entitlements :entitlements.plist /path/to/.app/

Using above mentioned command doing signing of iOS application but during command run getting warning as below

Warning: Specifying ':' in the path is deprecated and will not work in a future release

Instead using ":" which argument to use to not see above mentioned warning

XCode version used : 13.2

Comment: What was `:entitlements.plist` even supposed to mean here? Is that supposed to be the pathname of a new file to direct the output to?

Comment: Yes ":" syntax is used to create new file and direct output to /path/to/.app/